# Tshark running on CentOS inside Docker: Operation not permitted: '/usr/sbin/dumpcap'

Tags: python, docker, centos, wireshark, tshark

I'm trying to run a Docker image with Tshark on CentOS. Unfortunately I keep getting this `PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/sbin/dumpcap'` error.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  tshark:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    container_name: tshark
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos

RUN  yum -y update && \
     yum -y install epel-release && \
     yum -y install python36 \
     yum -y install libcap2-bin wireshark && yum clean all && \
     curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && \
     /usr/bin/python36 get-pip.py && \
     rm get-pip.py && \
     pip install pyshark && \
     pip install tqdm requests && \
     ln -s /usr/bin/python36 /usr/bin/python3

# add extra user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash shark
RUN usermod -aG wireshark shark
RUN newgrp wireshark
RUN chgrp wireshark /usr/sbin/dumpcap
RUN chmod 750 /usr/sbin/dumpcap
RUN setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/sbin/dumpcap

# wireshark fixes
# RUN newgrp wireshark

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# switch user
USER shark

CMD ["python3", "process.py"]
```

My process.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
import pyshark

capture = pyshark.LiveRingCapture(interface='eth0')

for packet in capture.sniff_continuously(packet_count=5):
    print('Just arrived:', packet)
```

I tried different solutions. It seems it has something to do with the fact it won't run while using a root user, or a user which hasn't got the right permissions. Hopefully someone can help me out. This is the result I keep getting after running `docker-compose up --build`:

```
tshark    | Traceback (most recent call last):
tshark    |   File "process.py", line 6, in <module>
tshark    |     for packet in capture.sniff_continuously(packet_count=5):
tshark    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/capture.py", line 207, in _packets_from_tshark_sync
tshark    |     tshark_process = existing_process or self.eventloop.run_until_complete(self._get_tshark_process())
tshark    |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
tshark    |     return future.result()
tshark    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyshark/capture/live_capture.py", line 89, in _get_tshark_process
tshark    |     stderr=self._stderr_output())
tshark    |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/subprocess.py", line 225, in create_subprocess_exec
tshark    |     stderr=stderr, **kwds)
tshark    |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1194, in subprocess_exec
tshark    |     bufsize, **kwargs)
tshark    |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 200, in _make_subprocess_transport
tshark    |     **kwargs)
tshark    |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_subprocess.py", line 39, in __init__
tshark    |     stderr=stderr, bufsize=bufsize, **kwargs)
tshark    |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 706, in _start
tshark    |     universal_newlines=False, bufsize=bufsize, **kwargs)
tshark    |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
tshark    |     restore_signals, start_new_session)
tshark    |   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
tshark    |     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
tshark    | PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/usr/sbin/dumpcap'
tshark exited with code 1
```

I am almost sure it's an issue with wireshark itself and not pyshark. Tried to install pyshark using `pip install pyshark --user` but same error, still.

Comment: Do you have `selinux` enabled?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/757606/how-to-enable-selinux-inside-of-a-centos-docker-container so it seems to be disabled by default.